# How to load local HTML file in Scrapy Splash?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to load a local HTML file using Scrapy Splash and take save it as PNG/JPEG and then delete the HTML file

```
script = """
splash:go(args.url)
return splash:png()
"""
resp = requests.post('http://localhost:8050/run', json={
    'lua_source': script,
    'url': 'file://my_file.html'
})
resp.content
```

It returns me

> Failed loading page (Protocol "" is unknown) Network error #301

I have also tried

```
yield SplashRequest(url=filepath, 
                    callback=self.parse_result,
                    meta={'filepath': filepath},
                    args={
                        'wait': 0.5,
                        'png': 1,
                    },
                    endpoint='render.html',
                )
```

But I get

> 2020-04-23 12:07:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0):

You’re using Scrapy Splash to communicate [ScrapingHub](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to generate the image. This only supports HTTP(s) requests. You can clone their repository and implement the changes.

Although it might be easier to serve the HTML through a web server. You can use localhost. However, if you’re running the ScrapingHub through a docker, then you’ll need to allow access to the ports.

Comment: Actually "then you could serve the HTML from a web server (as the code should be able to scrape localhost)." is wrong even serving from local host doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use localhost by the bottom two links. Some of the people mentioned **turning off** *Crawlera* fixed their problem. It could be trying to route your requests through online IPs to reach your localhost which would be problematic.

[Scrapy Splash on Ubuntu server: got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744546/scrapy-splash-on-ubuntu-server-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-encoding/42744668#42744668)

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/108

Comment: you mean by crawlera the proxy provider?

Comment: Why would I using a paid proxy provider while scraping local HTML more importantly, if crawlera middleware is active you can't open local HTML with it. Your "answer" is wrong on many levels.